# KeywordQuery with "last modified by" and "last modified date"

Tags: publishing-site, search

How do you use a `KeywordQuery` to **search for "last modified by" and "last modified date"?**

This is for SharePoint 2010 Server, with publishing pages and document libraries, so "enterprise search". I'm currently using the query like so:

```
new KeywordQuery(SPContext.Current.Site)
{
    QueryText = "query",
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `KeywordQuery`, both of these are easily searched upon.

**For "last modified by",** you can simply add:

```
and Author:"domain\user"
```

...to the `Query`. This will only return items who were last updated by *domain\user*.

**For "last modified date",** this is most easily filtered upon when the search results are already gathered, by using a `RowFilter` on a `DataView` made from the `DataTable` returned by the KeywordQuery:

```
dataView.RowFilter = "write <= '1989-12-24'";
```