# Getting ModifiedBy in a KeywordQuery

Tags: search, fast-search

I want to da a keywordquery because it shoul work with Sharepoint Enterprise and FAST Search.
And all i want is to get the 10 last modified documents from a search application.

My problem is, that i can't get the column ModifiedBy. I'm adding the column this way:

```
keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("ModifiedBy");
```

But when I execute this query I get the following error:

```
Property doesn't exist or is used in a manner inconsistent with schema settings.
```

There is a similar article on the problem but there query should bring only documents from a special author.
[KeywordQuery with "last modified by" and "last modified date"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/9814/keywordquery-with-last-modified-by-and-last-modified-date)

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I achieved it in the following simple way. I set the Maanged Property "ModifiedBy" to retrievable. Done it the following way:

```
                SearchServiceApplication searchApplication = SearchService.Service.SearchApplications.GetValue<SearchServiceApplication>(searchApplictionInfo.SearchServiceApplicationId);
                var searchSchema = new Schema(searchApplication);


                ManagedProperty managedProperty = searchSchema.AllManagedProperties["ModifiedBy"];
                managedProperty.Retrievable = true;
                managedProperty.Update();
```

This way you can access "ModifiedBy" through Keywordquery.

Comment: You could try to use the property "write" instead, which is what FAST uses for the last modified date.

Answer (score 2):

The ModifiedBy column has to be accessed as 'Author', you don't have to specify a specific value as stated in the link you provided. To get ModifiedBy back, use Author.

Comment: Sorry that doesn't work. I edited a document with another user -> Column Modifiedby at the library changed -> made full crawl -> Author hasn't changed